# Как сделать EditText многоязычным?

Tags: java, android, edittext

EditText позволяет вводить текст только на английском языке (если установить текст программно, то на любом). Как сделать так, чтобы можно было вводить текст на любом языке в EditText?

Сам код :

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/ed_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
            android:hint="название" // вот так русский текст он выводит
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:padding="16dp" />
```

Comment: Очень странно. По умолчанию - на любом языке ввод принимается. Опишите подробнее как вы сделали так, что не работает. Или как вы решили, что это не работает?

Comment: У меня это не работало с самого начала. Я  просто создала EditText, ничего не меняя, русские буквы с самого начала не разрешал вводить.  Хотя если поставить русский текст программно, то он принимает.

Comment: Ничего не понял. Подробнее пожалуйста. Начиная с места "просто создала `EditText`". Не очень понятно, речь идет об эмуляторе или реальном девайсе, как выглядит разметка/код создания `EditText`

Comment: речь идет об эмуляторе. С

Comment: Возможно, у вас на эмуляторе на самом русский язык не установлен. Попробуйте через настройки в эмуляторе язык нужный установить

Comment: теперь работает, сппасибо

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, у вас на эмуляторе на самом русский язык не установлен. Попробуйте через настройки в эмуляторе язык нужный установить.